# Android Worker thread freezes Main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout

I am working on an app that implements a custom ListView that contains images. I was able to get the listview to download and cache the images, but I would like to move the downloading onto a separate thread. To do so, I created a *CachedLogoDownloader* class who's goal is to asynchronously download the images and save them in memory to be accessed later by the custom Adapter class.

The problem is that the thread holds up the entire UI. Even when the code in the run() was just a "thread.sleep()" the UI stopped whenever the request for a logo image occurred. Similarly, placing an infinite loop in the run() caused the program to hang indefinitely.

```
class CachedLogoDownloader{

private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
Context context;
ArrayList<String> FIDs;
Thread runner;

public CachedLogoDownloader(Context inContext){
    this.context = inContext;

    //list of company logos (by FID) to be downloaded
    FIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

    //asynchronous downloader thread (single thread for lower-end devices. Shouldn't be much slower to get the images, though)
    runner = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(String FID:FIDs){
                Log.d(Cloud.DEBUG_TAG, "Icon Runnable for: " + FID);
                Bitmap tempImage = Cloud.lookupIcon(context, FID);
                cache.put(FID, tempImage);
                FIDs.remove(FID);                           
            }

        }
    });
}

public Bitmap getLogo(Company aCompany){

    String currentFID = aCompany.getFID();

    //if the image has already been cached, return the cached image
    if(cache.containsKey(currentFID))
    {
        return cache.get(currentFID);
    }
    else
    {
        //add the logo to the list of logos to be downloaded                
        FIDs.add(currentFID);

        //if the downloader thread completed (or hasn't started yet) make it download stuff.
        if(!runner.isAlive()){
            runner.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            runner.run();
        }

        //return null for now (until next time, whent the image will be in the cache!.)
        return null;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Instead of runner.run() you should use runner.start() otherwise your thread run() method actually executes in the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> runner.run();

That is not starting a separate thread, but just executing the contents of the run method on the calling thread. You probably want

> runner.start();

Also, you cannot start a Thread more than once, so

> if(!runner.isAlive()){

this check is probably not very useful. Start the thread when you need the image (or when you start the application), and then just wait for it to do its work. If you need more complex logic, such as thread pooling or error handling, you should probably just use a library for asynchronous image loading.